# How html elements placed in document object

Tags: html, web

I am trying to understand what are tags or elements in (HTML) document Object. How they constructed in DOM, and are they objects or functions? If there are any good tutorial on this topic can you send me ?

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a programming language, so it doesn't have any of the usual constructs: flow control structures, variables, objects... Don't get confused though with other languages built on top of HTML, such as JavaScript and its DOM API.

Comment: You seem to be a beginner in web developing. The best tutorial website I can think of for beginners is : https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Try https://www.w3schools.com

Comment: @MaheshSuthar there are not the answer

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp check this. When you visit w3schools.com then there is a menu at left and in that menu there is option for element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HyperText Markup Language is a language to describe a document made up of nested **tags** that provide semantic information about the text and media within that document. Tags can indicate header text (`h1`, `h2`, etc), paragraphs (`p`), links (`a`), etc.

When a browser consumes an HTML document, it creates a Document Object Model or DOM, in memory. Within that, tags are converted into Elements. These are objects that represent the semantic entities that the HTML document described. The DOM is essentially a tree object and Elements are nodes on the tree.

Elements can be (and often are) created programmatically.

Elements are not the only thing in the DOM. You'll also find text nodes too.

In summary, tags are a textual representation of semantic components of a marked-up document in HTML. Elements are their programmatic equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Tag/Element is the same thing. You could say that they are functions but they are not since html is not a programming language. Most tags need to be closed after being opened like this: `<tag></tag>`.They are used to add a specific element to your website like a button. Tags can also have attributes like this: `<tag attr="something"></tag>`. There is a good explanation on how all this works in w3schools website: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

An HTML element usually consists of a start tag <> and end tag , with the content inserted in between:

My first paragraph.